# Connection compression with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, compression

I am working on a project that has multiple remote devices uploading data to a single MySQL database. (Some of these devices use a cell modem with a data cap)

Each device uploads power usage data with 126 columns of Floating point numbers with precision of 4(xx.1234) every 2 seconds.

Additionally a 208 column average is uploaded around 2200 times a day. at 1, 5 and 15 minute intervals. I could probably just calculate these from the 2 second data but it was much easier and less cpu intensive to do the calculations on the raw data in python and this is just for testing out the idea.

Highest data usage per day I've seen is 130 MiB

csv version of single rows.

```
# id, dtime, hz, min_v1, avg_v1, max_v1, min_v2, avg_v2, max_v2, min_v3, avg_v3, max_v3, min_i1, avg_i1, max_i1, min_i2, avg_i2, max_i2, min_i3, avg_i3, max_i3, i_n, l1_kw_pa, l2_kw_pb, l3_kw_pc, avg_kw_t, l1_kvar_qa, l2_kvar_qb, l3_kvar_qc, avg_kvar_t, l1_kva_sa, l2_kva_sb, l3_kva_sc, avg_kva_t, l1_pf_pfa, l2_pf_pfb, l3_pf_pfc, avg_pf_t, power_dmd, kvar_dmd, kva_dmd, kwh_imp, kvarh_imp, kwh_t, kvarh_t, kvah_t, v1_thd, v2_thd, v3_thd, i1_thd, i2_thd, i3_thd, p_seq_real_v, p_seq_comp_v, n_seq_real_v, n_seq_comp_v, z_seq_real_v, z_seq_comp_v, p_seq_real_i, p_seq_comp_i, n_seq_real_i, n_seq_comp_i, z_seq_real_i, z_seq_comp_i, v2_pa, v3_pa, i1_pa, i2_pa, i3_pa, vh1_2, vh1_3, vh1_5, vh1_7, vh1_9, vh1_11, vh1_13, vh1_odd, vh1_even, vh1_cf, vh2_2, vh2_3, vh2_5, vh2_7, vh2_9, vh2_11, vh2_13, vh2_odd, vh2_even, vh2_cf, vh3_2, vh3_3, vh3_5, vh3_7, vh3_9, vh3_11, vh3_13, vh3_odd, vh3_even, vh3_cf, ih1_3, ih1_5, ih1_7, ih1_9, ih1_11, ih1_13, ih1_odd, ih1_even, ih1_kf, ih2_3, ih2_5, ih2_7, ih2_9, ih2_11, ih2_13, ih2_odd, ih2_even, ih2_kf, ih3_3, ih3_5, ih3_7, ih3_9, ih3_11, ih3_13, ih3_odd, ih3_even, ih3_kf
1, 2015-03-09 20:12:05, 59.97, 123.1, 122.992, 123.1, 122.5, 122.381, 122.5, 121.8, 121.749, 121.9, 0, 1.91508, 0, 0, 13.4917, 0, 0, 7.38669, 0, 19.9551, -5.54378, 226.589, 127.961, 348.94, 235.676, 1631.89, -887.699, 978.145, 235.981, 1650.68, 899.93, 2785.75, -0.02348, 0.13701, 0.14203, 0.125, 47.335, 1299.89, 3203.01, 1272600, 863619, 1272850, 863720, 1846930, 0.0148, 0.0148, 0.0123, , , , 122.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, -0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 119.9, 240.2, 92, 203.8, 160.1, , , , , , , , , , 1.428, , , , , , , , , , 1.434, , , , , , , , , , 1.427, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 

# id, dtime, min_hz, avg_hz, max_hz, min_min_v1, avg_avg_v1, max_max_v1, min_min_v2, avg_avg_v2, max_max_v2, min_min_v3, avg_avg_v3, max_max_v3, min_min_i1, avg_avg_i1, max_max_i1, min_min_i2, avg_avg_i2, max_max_i2, min_min_i3, avg_avg_i3, max_max_i3, min_i_n, avg_i_n, max_i_n, min_l1_kw_pa, avg_l1_kw_pa, max_l1_kw_pa, min_l2_kw_pb, avg_l2_kw_pb, max_l2_kw_pb, min_l3_kw_pc, avg_l3_kw_pc, max_l3_kw_pc, min_avg_kw_t, avg_avg_kw_t, max_avg_kw_t, min_l1_kvar_qa, avg_l1_kvar_qa, max_l1_kvar_qa, min_l2_kvar_qb, avg_l2_kvar_qb, max_l2_kvar_qb, min_l3_kvar_qc, avg_l3_kvar_qc, max_l3_kvar_qc, min_avg_kvar_t, avg_avg_kvar_t, max_avg_kvar_t, min_l1_kva_sa, avg_l1_kva_sa, max_l1_kva_sa, min_l2_kva_sb, avg_l2_kva_sb, max_l2_kva_sb, min_l3_kva_sc, avg_l3_kva_sc, max_l3_kva_sc, min_avg_kva_t, avg_avg_kva_t, max_avg_kva_t, min_l1_pf_pfa, avg_l1_pf_pfa, max_l1_pf_pfa, min_l2_pf_pfb, avg_l2_pf_pfb, max_l2_pf_pfb, min_l3_pf_pfc, avg_l3_pf_pfc, max_l3_pf_pfc, min_avg_pf_t, avg_avg_pf_t, max_avg_pf_t, max_power_dmd, max_kvar_dmd, max_kva_dmd, max_kwh_imp, max_kvarh_imp, max_kwh_t, max_kvarh_t, max_kvah_t, min_v1_thd, avg_v1_thd, max_v1_thd, min_v2_thd, avg_v2_thd, max_v2_thd, min_v3_thd, avg_v3_thd, max_v3_thd, min_i1_thd, avg_i1_thd, max_i1_thd, min_i2_thd, avg_i2_thd, max_i2_thd, min_i3_thd, avg_i3_thd, max_i3_thd, p_seq_real_v, p_seq_comp_v, n_seq_real_v, n_seq_comp_v, z_seq_real_v, z_seq_comp_v, p_seq_real_i, p_seq_comp_i, n_seq_real_i, n_seq_comp_i, z_seq_real_i, z_seq_comp_i, v2_pa, v3_pa, i1_pa, i2_pa, i3_pa, vh1_2, vh1_3, vh1_5, vh1_7, vh1_9, vh1_11, vh1_13, min_vh1_odd, avg_vh1_odd, max_vh1_odd, min_vh1_even, avg_vh1_even, max_vh1_even, min_vh1_cf, avg_vh1_cf, max_vh1_cf, vh2_2, vh2_3, vh2_5, vh2_7, vh2_9, vh2_11, vh2_13, min_vh2_odd, avg_vh2_odd, max_vh2_odd, min_vh2_even, avg_vh2_even, max_vh2_even, min_vh2_cf, avg_vh2_cf, max_vh2_cf, vh3_2, vh3_3, vh3_5, vh3_7, vh3_9, vh3_11, vh3_13, min_vh3_odd, avg_vh3_odd, max_vh3_odd, min_vh3_even, avg_vh3_even, max_vh3_even, min_vh3_cf, avg_vh3_cf, max_vh3_cf, ih1_3, ih1_5, ih1_7, ih1_9, ih1_11, ih1_13, min_ih1_odd, avg_ih1_odd, max_ih1_odd, min_ih1_even, avg_ih1_even, max_ih1_even, min_ih1_kf, avg_ih1_kf, max_ih1_kf, ih2_3, ih2_5, ih2_7, ih2_9, ih2_11, ih2_13, min_ih2_odd, avg_ih2_odd, max_ih2_odd, min_ih2_even, avg_ih2_even, max_ih2_even, min_ih2_kf, avg_ih2_kf, max_ih2_kf, ih3_3, ih3_5, ih3_7, ih3_9, ih3_11, ih3_13, min_ih3_odd, avg_ih3_odd, max_ih3_odd, min_ih3_even, avg_ih3_even, max_ih3_even, min_ih3_kf, avg_ih3_kf, max_ih3_kf
1, 2015-03-25 12:05:03, 59.9351, 59.9515, 59.9651, 123, 123.165, 123.5, 122.2, 122.379, 122.7, 121.9, 121.986, 122.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22.8891, 0, 0, 6.69319, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2689.78, 2741.23, 2827.1, 761.323, 767.21, 775.285, 3455.01, 3509.49, 3597.13, 0, 0, 0, -47.318, -29.5382, -16.3021, 142.391, 147.547, 152.868, 97.1515, 117.985, 131.682, 0, 0, 0, 2744.95, 2800.07, 2883.35, 799.135, 818.643, 854.545, 3545.14, 3619.77, 3699.94, 0.99903, 0.99903, 0.99903, 0.97461, 0.978048, 0.98087, 0.8978, 0.936465, 0.95534, 0.95832, 0.968614, 0.97364, 3497.05, 154.864, 3610.55, 529.2, 46.8, 529.8, 47.3, 568.1, 0.0147, 0.0149417, 0.0153, 0.0155, 0.0158617, 0.0164, 0.0138, 0.0141883, 0.0149, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122.452, -0.0783333, 0.241667, 0.103333, 0.308333, -0.0666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 119.985, 240.133, 0, 121.318, 250.655, 0, 0.01061, 0, 0.003965, 0, 0, 0, 0.0131, 0.013455, 0.014, 0.0058, 0.006575, 0.007, 1.429, 1.43403, 1.435, 0, 0.0117267, 0, 0.00466333, 0, 0, 0, 0.0142, 0.0146267, 0.0152, 0.0055, 0.00624333, 0.0066, 1.435, 1.43673, 1.438, 0, 0.0110717, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0128, 0.0132333, 0.0143, 0.0042, 0.00523333, 0.0059, 1.428, 1.42912, 1.43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

My  current set up uses Sqlalchemy and python-MySQLdb to communicate with the database. I need to find a way to cut down on the data usage, and if possible do it without sending data less frequently

In case it matters Each remote device is a small raspberry pi like computer.

For reference this is a link to my development web server where you can see what the point of this project is.
http://104.131.181.35/live/voltsandamps
Its still a work in progress.

For the past couple of days I have been researching MySQL compression protocol but haven't found a way to implement it with sqlalchemy or any other python database connector.

I know that python_mysqldb has a compress flag but I can't figure out how to use it. especially while its being used as the driver for sqlalchemy, which i'm willing to drop if necessary.

Is this possible? and if not is there another solution that would work better for this.

Any help would be apreciated.

EDIT:

I ended up writing a web service like what @paidhima recommended.  Each device sends data once every 1-30 minutes. The data format is basically a compressed json string, with a version, time-stamp(s), and array(s) of values. The web server then decompresses the received data and inserts it into the DB. When I first asked this question I knew next to nothing about databases and web development in general. Its funny to look back in time a year.  Final results with the web service: I achieved about an 10:1 compression ratio (between 88 and 92%). Each device averages about 10 - 15MB per day.  After a short time having remote devices connect directly to the server, I began to see that this wasn't a solution suited for anything other than a development environment. Security concerns, firewall issues, too many dropped connections and just general research lead me to drop the direct connection, and write a simple web service.

With the direct DB connection, I was able to get it down to about 70-80 MB a day per device. Thats with prepared statements, and connection compression enabled.

The web service is written in python and without the database interaction code, is only about 250 lines of code (for client and server). Thanks for you excellent advice @eggyal and @paidhima. I'm completely self taught, and have only been able to get as far as I have thanks to individuals like yourselves that contribute advice and answer questions.

Comment: I see that MySQLdb does include a "compress" flag for connections, though I've never used it.  You might want to consider how your data is moving across that connection though.  Would it make sense to extend your web server to handle JSON requests, instead of allowing direct database connections?

Comment: @eggyal, I used nload and vnstat to come up with the usage numbers, and I assumed (yes I know, bad idea) that most of the data it logged would be from the mysql connection as the only other option would be the autossh connection that is my method of management for the devices. Maybe I have something else going on I don't know about... The current nload sustained average bandwidth is 26kbit/s. I'll do some checking and make sure.

Comment: @paidhima short answer. I don't know.. Long answer: My web server is currently just a simple flask application with socketio and a few other bits. I started learning web-development about 2 months ago. Right now the database connections are handled by the flask/python side and socketio is used to send data to the  browser. If it makes a difference the remote devices are sometimes behind firewalls, so short of a reverse ssh or vpn (which i haven't gotten around to yet) the only option I have to send data all the time otherwise i would do the analysis at ea. device and just send data per request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Identifying Potential Improvements

If you inspect the packets that are transmitted to MySQL upon the insertion of each record—which should be easy to do with a mere [packet sniffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer), since (unless you're [connecting over SSL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/ssl-connections.html)) the communications are neither encrypted nor compressed—you will notice:

1. The SQL `INSERT` statement, which includes the full list of column names,  is transmitted *every time*.
2. The floating-point values are transmitted as strings, requiring up to 36 characters *each*.

Both result in significant unnecessary network utilisation that would be avoided by using [MySQL's binary prepared statement protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/prepared-statements.html) instead (the SQL command could be sent to the server only once, and thereafter only data values would be transmitted *in their respective storage formats* for each insertion attempt).

Of the MySQL drivers that are supported by SQLAlchemy, only Oracle's "official" one ([MySQL Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/)), provides an API for this functionality (whilst [oursql](https://pythonhosted.org/oursql/) also uses the protocol, it doesn't reuse statements that are sent repeatedly).

#### SQLAlchemy

Unfortunately, SQLAlchemy's [mysqlconnector dialect](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqlconnector.py) does not currently utilise these features.

Whilst there are still some things you *can* do in SQLAlchemy to reduce network utilisation (for example, in Core you could prevent the full list of column names being transmitted), the reality is that you won't ever do as well as could be achieved with the binary prepared statement protocol.

## Recommendations

Therefore I recommend either:

- extending SQLAlchemy's mysqlconnector dialect to support such functionality (more work, but of considerable value to the community at large); or
- dropping SQLAlchemy (at least for these insertion operations) and instead using the MySQL Connector/Python driver directly.

In pursuing either approach, you could also enable [packet compression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/compression.html) at the same time.

#### Example

```
import time
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='raspberryPi_1234',
                              password='foobar',
                              host='mysql.example.com',
                              database='voltsandamps',
                              autocommit=true,
                              compress=true)  # compress the connection

cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)            # this is what SQLAlchemy is missing

stmt = "INSERT INTO power_readings VALUES (" + ",".join(126*["?"]) + ")"

while true:
    cursor.execute(stmt, getPowerReadings())
    time.sleep(2)
```

## Final Thoughts

If you need to reduce network utilisation yet further, you might consider using [stored procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-procedure.html) to encapsulate your `INSERT` command—not only because a `CALL myProc(...)` command will almost always be shorter than the underlying `INSERT` command, but also because it enables one to do adopt some extremely aggressive techniques including:

- rebasing your data: if values tend to fall within a certain range, *you need only transmit the offset* from the base of that range (which might permit use of a smaller data type during transmission)—rebasing to the actual value could then be performed within the stored procedure (and the base itself could be set using a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html)); and
- in extremis, one could compress one's data on the client and pack into a binary string, then unpack and decompress at the server—thus maximising the usage of every last bit (also a single string value would incur less management overhead than multiple separate values of the same aggregate length).

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the detailed answer with example code. I'll be sure to report back with the before and after results. If I had a little more time on my hands I would look into extending sqlalchemy, and will put it on my todo list anyway. Thanks again, i'm going to go ahead and mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @bigjake: Curious how much success you had with this?  Do you have the before/after results?